# How To Correctly Use Array-Lists In Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

For my school work I've been given the task to create a  simple bookstore program for Java. So far I've managed to create a working program to display and store data once its been inputted by the user, my problem now is that I want to show the data once the user ends the program so all the data they entered will be displayed. What I want is for the Author, Price, Publisher and ISBN inputted data be displayed under these headings. I know you use Array lists to do this but I don't have any idea how to do this in Java, any help is much appreciated.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[]
        title=new String[100],
        author=new String[100],
        publisher=new String[100],
        ISBN=new String[100];
        boolean endinput = false;
        boolean Yes = true;
        double[] price=new double[100];
        System.out.println("Welcome To Kieran's Bookstore");
        while (Yes) {

            System.out.println("Input The Title:");
            title[0] = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Input The Author:");
            author[0] = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Input The Price Of The Book:");
            scan.next();
            System.out.println("Input The Publisher:");
            publisher[0] = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Input The ISBN:");
            ISBN[0] = scan.next();
            System.out.println("Would you like to continue?(Yes/endinput)");
            String ans = scan.next();
            if (ans.equals("endinput") || (scan.equals("endinput"))) {
                Yes = false;
                System.exit(0);

            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: ArrayLIst is used to hold a list of objects, not to display data.  You can print the contents of Arrays to the console as easily as the contents of ArrayLists, by looping through the array and printing the string representation of each item.

Comment: @smitty1 he explicitly wrote: "I want to show the data once the user ends the program so all the data they entered will be displayed" so the OP is right: a data-structure is required to hold all the data.

Comment: @alfasin the OP stated "What I want is for the Author, Price, Publisher and ISBN inputted data be displayed under these headings. I know you use arry lists to do this" which is false.  Yes, you will need a data structure, but it doesn't require an ArrayList to display the data

Comment: @Kieran Fleming You're looping structure is flawed.  Although you set your arrays to length of 100, you never change anything but index 0, so every iteration overwrites the previous iteration's data.  You should increment the index on each iteration.  Also, in the case a user should enter more than 100 entries, it will throw index out of bounds exception.  You should consider replacing all your String[] arrays with List<String> as lists are resizable where arrays are not.  Either that, or gracefully end the loop when the index reached 100;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create an ArrayList using the following syntax:

```
    ArrayList<type> name = new ArrayList<type>();
```

So an example could be:

```
    //It's common practice to make these plural, to signify it's an array(list)
    ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();
```

You add an item to the ArrayList using:

```
    //Keep in mind that the Object you're adding has to be the same type as the type you specified the ArrayList to be. 
    name.add(thingThatYouWantToAdd);
```

Example:

```
    titles.add("This is just a title");
```

There are also one thing I'd like to improve about your code:
Don't use `Yes` as your boolean name for in the while loop. I'd recommend using `running`, as it immediately makes it clear what you mean by `while(running)`.

Comment: Thank you, i'm still slightly confused on what to do. Where would I add the code above in my program?  Underneath the system.exit or before that?

Comment: @KieranFleming you initialize the lists (ArrayList<String> titles = new ArrayList<String>();) at the start, where currently the title = new String[100] is, and you repeat it for every list you want to make.

The title[0] = scan.next(); you should replace with titles.add(scan.next());
And this you also repeat for every list.

Comment: do I need to a use a system.print to display the arrylist? so people can see their data?

Comment: Yes. There are two options. Let's suppose you have an ArrayList called list containing the following strings: "this", "is", "an", "example".

You can do System.out.println(list);
This will output [this, is, an, example]

Or you could iterate through it with a for loop:
for(i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
  System.out.println(list.get(i))
}

This will output:
this
is
an
example

Each on a separate line. Depends on the situation which you should use of course

Comment: Thank you again. Sorry for all the questions

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @K-llojimans answer:

There are different types of Lists possible in Java. They all can be held in a similar type of variable. This variable type is called List.

For example:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> myList2 = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Also, starting with Java 1.7 you don't need to explicitly state the list type during initialization. So your code can look like this:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Thank you, so if i do this and create array lists for Title, Author, Price,  Publisher and ISBN it will display the data that the user previously inputted beforehand?

Comment: You need to first create the lists, secondly insert data into the lists, and once you have the data you need inside the lists, you can print them out. Like so:             System.out.println("This is my list: " + myList.toString()); @KieranFleming

Comment: i'm not quite sure what you mean Alex, I have to input data into the lists not the user?

Comment: @KieranFleming The data the use inputs is stored in scan.next(). It's your responsibility to take it from there, and store it where you want (for example in a list). For example, right now, you receive the data and store it in arrays (ISBN, Price, etc.).